# ReportLab & Jython?

Tags: python, jython, reportlab

I'm trying to get **reportlab** to run under **Jython** (2.5.2), but it fails to install:

```
$ easy_install reportlab

Searching for reportlab>=2.4
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/reportlab/
Reading http://www.reportlab.com/
Best match: reportlab 2.5
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/reportlab/reportlab-2.5.tar.gz#md5=cdf8b87a6cf1501de1b0a8d341a217d3
Processing reportlab-2.5.tar.gz
Running reportlab-2.5/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/04/nrrmlfvx05l43fj6rljc2z400000gq/T/easy_install-x2cwzJ/reportlab-2.5/egg-dist-tmp-D_S74b
################################################
#Attempting install of _rl_accel, sgmlop & pyHnj
#extensions from '/private/var/folders/04/nrrmlfvx05l43fj6rljc2z400000gq/T/easy_install-x2cwzJ/reportlab-2.5/src/rl_addons/rl_accel'
################################################
################################################
#Attempting install of _renderPM
#extensions from '/private/var/folders/04/nrrmlfvx05l43fj6rljc2z400000gq/T/easy_install-x2cwzJ/reportlab-2.5/src/rl_addons/renderPM'
# installing without freetype no ttf, sorry!
# You need to install a static library version of the freetype2 software
# If you need truetype support in renderPM
# You may need to edit setup.cfg (win32)
# or edit this file to access the library if it is installed
################################################
Downloading standard T1 font curves
Finished download of standard T1 font curves
error: Setup script exited with error: Compiling extensions is not supported on Jython
```

The error seems to occur when `setup.py` tries to install the **renderPM** extension.
Is there a way to install reportlab without the renderPM extension ?

Comment: maybe i'm mistaken, but i think reportlab relies on c-extensions, so jython is probably out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to install (and it even seems to work) by doing this:

```
curl -O http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/reportlab/reportlab-2.5.tar.gz
tar zxf reportlab-2.5.tar.gz
cd reportlab*
rm -rf src/rl_addons
jython setup.py install
```

Basically, this removes the native extensions, which the setup doesn't seem to mind (it will print warnings though).

Answer (score 0):

Jython cannot use any modules that require c extensions.

from the [reportlab prerequisites page](http://www.reportlab.com/software/installation/)

> Download and install Python Imaging Library for the relevant version of

ouch, [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) is a show stopper for jython.

Your choices are to

1. use one of the java pdf solutions like [iText](http://itextpdf.com/)
2. use any of the python template languages to create [XLS-FO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL_Formatting_Objects), then use the [Apache-FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) to convert to pdf

I've had good success with the latter as the XML you learn will always be a valid option for you no matter what language you work from in the future.

Comment: I'm not sure the docs are accurate. I found code in ReportLab's `util.py` that check for `javax.imageio` and make it available to ReportLab.